# Snappy data compression on Android

Tags: android, http, java-native-interface, compression, native

I want to know if there is any way of using snappy data compression on android. I found a java port of the c/c++ snappy library by [xerial](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=snappy%20java%20%22), but after adding it to my app and running it I get the error that there are no natives for armv7l.

I found another pure java library by [dain](https://github.com/dain/snappy), but it doesn't appear to be working. It just adds a space and the first character of the string to the existing string, without compressing it. For example, `HELLO` would become `HHELLO`.

Is there any other way of using snappy on android?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fast pure java implementation here: 
https://github.com/flanglet/kanzi/blob/master/java/src/kanzi/function/SnappyCodec.java

An example is available here:
https://github.com/flanglet/kanzi/blob/master/java/src/kanzi/test/TestSnappyCodec.java.

Although not tested on Android, it is expected to work without change.

Answer (score 0):

Another pure java implementation for the record: https://github.com/dain/snappy

@flanglet, I'm interested to know your opinion about this lib. How does it compare to the kanzi implementation ?

Comment: I did some (limited) testing 2 years ago and both Java implementations were a tie in terms of speed. See https://github.com/flanglet/kanzi/wiki/Performance-of-Snappy-and-LZ4-Codecs. The implementation you are referring to is named iq80 in the test. Since the test code is available, feel free to use it with your own data.